# Transparent object in scatter causes Matlab to crash

Tags: matlab

I'm attempting to use `patch` and `alpha` to produce a scatter plot with a shadowed-like area. Though I had been able to do so in the past, at this time Matlab crashes whenever I use `alpha`.

This is a sample code that is currently crashing:

```
hdata = rand(20, 1);
vdata = rand(20, 1);
f = figure;
scatter(hdata, vdata, 'k', 'filled');
py = patch([0 0 1], [0 1 1], 'y');
alpha(py, .2);
set(gcf, 'PaperSize', [5 5]);
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', [0 0 5 5]);
print(f, '-dpdf', '/tmp/test');
```

I have attempted to use `-deps`, `-dpng`, and `-dpsc` as the driver for `print`. In the past I had been using `-dpsc`, and it worked here's a sample graph I generated:

[image]

I have attempted to use the `-opengl` option with `print`.

I have also attempted to download and use `export_figure`, but it's also causing Matlab to crash. I tried to export `png`s and `pdf`s, but both fail.

I have not upgraded Matlab since I last used this code succesfully. It's Matlab 7.11.0.584 (R2010b) for Linux 64-bit. I have certainly upgraded something else in my system that's causing Matlab to crash, but I have no idea what this might be. I'd be happy with any suggestions to find the culprit.

Comment: Could you add some more information about the crash (some messages)?

Comment: If it's any consolation, I find that Matlab crashes when I use `patch` or other routines that use it. I have never been able to create reproducible conditions that make it happen - but it happens. Some deep bug that's been there for years.

Comment: At which command does the crash occur ? when you set the `alpha` value or when you call the `print` command ?

Comment: @Hoki, it crashes when I call `print`.

Comment: @ThomasKilian, I receive a `MathWorks::System::FatalException` indicating segmentation violation, and a long stack trace follows.

Comment: Maybe if you post the first lines of the stack trace it will help to locate the cause.